# Display blank image after each non-blank image

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I want to display a images in a random order but have a blank image displayed after each image. I have the images displaying randomly but not sure how to make sure the blank image displays after each image. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the blank image you mean you want to display nothing into the axis. So to do so you may just call the command **cla** after displaying an image whenever you want to display a blank axis/image. This clears the previous image from the axis and simply shows a blank axis.

*e.g., Suppose you have two images to display and in between you want to display a blank image then the code to do so is.*

```
% show the first image
imshow('cameraman.tif')
% add a pause of 1 second
pause(1)
% clear the previous image from axis
cla
% add a pause of 1 second to view the blank axis
pause(1)
% display the 2nd image
imshow('coins.png')
```